# Batch: alternative to a multi-character eol

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, eol

I'm using batch to parse another batch file.

I want to skip comments by essentially setting

```
eol=rem
```

I haven't found a way to get this to work. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Use findstr to not find any lines that start with rem.

Comment: Some options; use a `For` loop with `Tokens=1*` and something similar to `Do If Not "%%A"=="REM", or use `FindStr/V` with possibly `\<REM\>`. It's hard to be specific when we cannot see the file(s) to parse, the method of parsing or the intent.

Comment: bxk21, you shouldn't put your answer into your question, there is nothing however stopping you from submitting it as an answer, and if it is your preferred one accepting it as such. Please note that `REM` need not be the first character on a line to be valid, hence the reason I suggested `\<REM\>`, meaning match the whole word REM. Also at present any concatenated line beginning with, for example; remote, remount, removable or remainder would be `rem`oved despite the fact it wasn't a `rem`ark.

Comment: @Compo, thanks. I've found a way to find what I need with regex in findstr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that this works:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b /v /i /r /C:"[    ]*rem[  ]" %BAT_FILE%') do (
    echo Uncommented Line: %%A
)
```

From https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html:

```
/b searches from the beginning of the string
/v searches for lines not matching the string
/i allows for "REM" as well as "rem"
/r /C: turns on regex:
[   ] is a block containing a space and a tab.
```

So, the regex searches for any amount of whitespace, the string "rem", then one piece of whitespace.